# Когда ставить двоеточие при перечислении?

Tags: синтаксис

> Сдала(:) 2 пульта, ключ, фонарь.

Answer (score 1):

Постановка двоеточия здесь факультативна и зависит от того, хотите ли вы придать фразе официально-деловой характер. Если да – поставьте двоеточие, если нет – не ставьте.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно. Но можно и без двоеточия.